# How do I use new fdisk table without reboot (kpartx)?

Tags: debian, fdisk

When I run fdisk and change the size of a partition, fdisk says at the end of its output:

```
The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
```

I'd like to do so without having to reboot (and then write a script that does it) How do I use [kpartx](http://linux.die.net/man/8/kpartx) to do this correctly? I've tried:

```
kpartx -f -v /dev/mmcblk0
```

Which outputs:

```
mmcblk0p1 : 0 102400 /dev/mmcblk0 2048
mmcblk0p2 : 0 7657472 /dev/mmcblk0 104448
```

and:

```
kpartx -a -v /dev/mmcblk0
```

which outputs:

```
device-mapper: reload ioctl on mmcblk0p1 failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on mmcblk0p1
add map mmcblk0p1 (0:0): 0 102400 linear /dev/mmcblk0 2048
device-mapper: reload ioctl on mmcblk0p2 failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on mmcblk0p2
add map mmcblk0p2 (0:0): 0 7657472 linear /dev/mmcblk0 104448
```

This is for an SD card in a raspi running debian.

EDIT: To clarify what I am trying to do; I am deleting an unused p3 from an SD Card and resizing p2 to fill the card. The card currently contains a small boot partition p1 and p2 is where the OS sits.

Comment: Is the SD card currently in use? (E.g., does it have a mounted filesystem on it?)

Comment: @derobert, yes it does. it has 2 partitions: a small boot partition and a larger main partition where the majority of the OS sits. I am just trying to expand the 2nd partition to fill the card.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the answer—you can't. The kernel won't reread a partition table unless the device isn't in use...

Comment: Does `partprobe` help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want `partx -u`, not `kpartx` ( which operates on device-mapper devices ).

Comment: What is the purpose of `-u` flag?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, to *update* the kernel partition table to match the on disk one.  A quick `man partx` would have answered this.

Comment: @Octopus This did it for me, where partprobe didn't. Partprobe then returned without that error.

Answer (score 6):

I believe @derobert (who commented on the original question) is likely correct. In the case of fdisking a partition that is currently being used it seems there is no other option than to reboot.

Even when I use `partprobe` (which is obtained with `apt-get install parted`) I get the following output:

```
Error: Partition(s) 2, 3 on /dev/mmcblk0 have been written, but we have 
been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they 
are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You 
should reboot now before making further changes.
```

Comment: I did the same thing, good news is, that i was able to unmount, run partprobe <device>, and remount both partitions without rebooting.  Unfortunately it still required downtime due to shutting down services.

Comment: More recent versions of `parted` / `partprobe` will not give such an error and can be used on a mounted partition without reboot.

Comment: @psusi , I'm using a recent version of `parted` but I still get the same error. The solution is to unmount the device before running `parted` on the device, then you don't have to reboot your system in order to inform the kernel to use the new partition instead of the old partition

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this problem because I forgot to unmount the device. After a:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb
```

fdisk worked correctly.

Comment: I still get an error: **Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Re-reading the partition table failed.: Device or resource busy**